# Wy js method toFixed() return NaN

Tags: javascript, html

I have two exactly the same simple web project,but one everything is working fine and the other not, tell me what the problem is, where a bug

when I enter something gives me the result NaN

I tried to do it without the method "toFixed()"all  works

[Here is example](http://jsbin.com/kulisegufa/1/)

Here is the code page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Конвертер валют</title>
     <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="page.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Converter">
    <hr>
   input value  <label for="inputValue"></label><input type="text" value="0.00" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                    onkeyup="count(this.value)"
                                                    onfocus="if (this.value == '0.00') this.value='';"
                                                    onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '0.00'; }"
                                                    id="inputValue">

    <p>Result</p>

    <ul>
        <li><input type="text" readonly value="0.00" 
                   onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '0.00'; }" id="conventUSD">
            <input type="text" id="value1" readonly size="1" value="USD">
            <input value= "5.553" readonly id="exchange1"></li>
        <li><input type="text" readonly value="0.00" 
                   onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '0.00'; }" id="conventRUB">
            <input type="text" id="value2" readonly size="1" value="RUB">
            <input value= "10.553" readonly id="exchange2"></li>
        <li><input type="text" readonly value="0.00" 
                   onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '0.00'; }" id="conventEUR">
            <input type="text" id="value3" readonly size="1" value="EUR">
            <input value= "15.553" readonly id="exchange3"></li>
        <li><input type="text" readonly value="0.00" 
                   onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '0.00'; }" id="conventUAH">
            <input type="text" id="value4" readonly size="1" value="PLN">
            <input  value= "20.553" readonly id="exchange4"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
            <body/>
<html/>
```

Here is js code

```
 function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = ((evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode);
    return !(charCode > 31 && (charCode != 46 && charCode != 44 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)));

}


function count(inputValue) {

    if (inputValue != "" && inputValue != "0.00") {

        $('#conventUSD').val(($("#exchange1").val() * inputValue).toFixed(4));
        $('#conventRUB').val(($("#exchange2").val() * inputValue).toFixed(4));
        $('#conventEUR').val(($("#exchange3").val() * inputValue).toFixed(4));
        $('#conventUAH').val(($("#exchange4").val() * inputValue).toFixed(4));

    } else {
        var defaultValue = "0.00";
        $('#conventUSD').val(defaultValue);
        $('#conventEUR').val(defaultValue);
        $('#conventRUB').val(defaultValue);
        $('#conventUAH').val(defaultValue);

    }

}
```

Pleas help me with this problem,because i tried everything and do not know where the problem!

Comment: What about it is not working? You haven't described the problem.

Comment: For what input does it produce `NaN`? It seems to work.

Comment: Result of count of my program is NaN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toFixed` is giving you `"NaN"` because either:

- `inputValue` is a string that cannot be converted to a number, or
- `#exchange1/2/3/4` has a value which is a string that cannot be converted to a number

...and so when you multiply `inputValue` by the value of one of those exchange boxes, you're getting the value `NaN`. When you call `toFixed` on `NaN` you get `"NaN"`.

Things to look for:

- Perhaps you need to trim whitespace before converting
- You certainly need to remove `,` before converting, `+"1,234"` is `NaN`
- Or you're allowing (other) non-numeric characters into fields (`keypress` is not the only way data gets into fields, and the check used by your `isNumberKey` looks pretty dodgy)

Comment: Thank you all right, your advice has helped now everything works

Comment: You'll laugh, I found the problem, the first draft of the work that the server sends the number to a point in the second coma and because of this method toFixed () produces NaN

excuse me that took your time